# aspnet core mvc access dependency indicted service inside ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to access the following service in an ActionFilterAttribute.

**IFooService** Service

```
 public interface IFooService<T>
 {
     List<T> GetFoos { get; set; }
 }
```

Implementation *FooService**

```
public class FooService : IFooService<int>
{
    public List<int> GetFoos()
    {
       //do something interesting here.
           return new List<int>();
    }
}
```

The above service is registered in aspnetcore dependency container as:

```
services.AddScoped<IFooService<int>, FooService>();
```

I want to consume the IFooService inside my attribute. However, at attribute level I don't know the type parameter.

is it possible to find the above service inside ActionFilterAttribute without knowning the type parameter? I want to be able to call the GetFoos method only on the interface.

//here is my attempt.

```
 public class FooActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
 {
      public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
      {
            //error here generic service require 1 argument. But i don't know how to pass this argument..
            var foo = (IFooService) context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IFooService<>));                                    
      }
 }
```

Comment: you created and registered it with `IFooService<int>` so that is what you should be asking for.

Comment: Hi Nkosi, I want to pack this attribute in a Nuget package. In this case i wont know the type always.

Comment: @John You code won't even compile. What you are hoping to achieve with Generic?

Answer (score -1):

You can store the type in the action filter as a parameter.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class FooActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public FooActionFilterAttribute(Type serviceType)
    {
        ServiceType = serviceType;
    }

    public Type ServiceType { get; }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var service =  context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(ServiceType) as FooService;                   
    }
}

// usage
[FooActionFilter(typeof(IFilterService<int>))]
public IActionResult ActionMethod()
{
}
```

Comment: There is no `IFooService` but `IFooService<T>` so your `as IFooService;` won't even compile. And will give the same error as the OP said in hist post => _//error here generic service require 1 argument. But i don't know how to pass this argument.._

Comment: @CodeNotFound Fixed to use `FooService`.  Thanks for picking up my mistake.  I'm just trying to give the OP some general direction.  I don't know what he's really trying to achieve.

Comment: Hum.. It will compile but you break the Liskov substitution principle. Your  code don't let me substitute with another implementation of `IFooService<T>`. Even for unit test I can't mock it.

Comment: @CodeNotFound As I said, I don't even know what the OP is trying to achieve.  My humblest apologies to Mr Liskov.

Comment: _I don't even know what the OP is trying to achieve_ asking more precisions on the OP post may help for precise answer also :)